# Execute Function in IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable, func

Using Linq, it is easy to execute a function to project an IEnumerable.

```
var orders = new List<Order>();
orders.Where(x => x.Id > 50).Select(x => new SomethingElse(x.Name));
```

Using EntityFramework and IQueryable, this is not possible. You instead get an unsupported exception at runtime because you cannot have a function inside the Select.

> Does not work:
>
> ```
> var db = new Order();
> db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Id > 50).Select(x => new SomethingElse(x.Name)).Take(10);
> ```

**Does there exist, or is it possible to create a way for the above to work?**

I understand it doesn't work because it cannot convert the function into something SQL can understand, however, if there was an extension method called 'Execute' that could execute in memory after executing all the linq before and after it, would that work?

> The database would pull only > 50 AND only TOP 10, only after would it be
>
> ```
> var db = new Order();
> db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Id > 50).Execute(x => new SomethingElse(x.Name)).Take(10);
> ```

**To clarify: The requirement is to keep it as IQueryable even after the Sleect()**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because you'd need to ship all the data back to the database to do the final part.

Typically you have an extra `Select` to get just the information you need within the query (using an anonymous type if there are multiple properties you need), then do all the rest locally:

```
var query = db.MyEntities
              .Where(x => x.Id > 50)
              .Select(x => x.Name) // All we need - keep the query cheap
              .Take(10)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(x => new SomethingElse(x));
```

Note that you may run into [`Queryable.AsQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003), which *does* produce an `IQueryable<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>` - but it doesn't do what you want. If the source isn't really a queryable, it will "fake" it but not connect it back to the database, which is what you're after.

Comment: The idea is to keep it as IQueryable even after the Select. So make it work in the order defined. So, have more filters AFTER the .Select()

Comment: @hatcyl: And my point is that no, you can't do that... but there are usually ways to avoid it being a problem, if what you're trying to do is feasible at all. If you need the database to use information which is only available locally, there's no clean and efficient way to do that.

Comment: I was afraid of that :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but you'll have to turn things around a little:

```
var db = new Order();
db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Id > 50)
             .Take(10)
             .AsEnumerable() // This will fetch data from the DB
             .Select(x => new SomethingElse(x.Name)); // Here, data is already fetched
```

The difference here is in the deference of execution: `Where()`, `Select()`, `Take()`, and several other operations are deferred - i.e. not called before the whole expression is evaluated, thus allowing the whole expression to be effectively mapped to an appropriate SQL statement.

`AsEnumerable()` on the other hand is a non-deferred operator. It allows the input sequence to be cast as a normal `IEnumerable<T>` sequence, allowing a Standard Query Operator method to be called.

Along with a few others operators like `ToList()`, `First()`, etc., this actually causes the first part of the query to be executed before it is itself applied. In this context, that means the first part of your query is translated to SQL and run. The result is passed on to the next operator - your `Select()` statement - which you can then use as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You could build the "WHERE":

```
     Expression<Func<Products, bool>> expresionFinal = p => p.Active;

    if (mydate.HasValue)
    {
        Expression<Func<Products, bool>> expresionDate = p => (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.CreatedDate) <= mydate);
        expresionFinal = PredicateBuilder.And(expresionFinal, expresionDate );
    }

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(codeProduct))
                {
                    Expression<Func<Products, bool>> expresionCode = c => (codeProduct== c.codProduct);
                    expresionFinal = PredicateBuilder.And(expresionFinal, expresionCode );
                }

    IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;


        query = query.Where(expresionFinal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course it is possible just call AsEnumerable() function like below:

```
var db = new Order();
db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Id > 50)
    .Take(10)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Execute(x => new SomethingElse(x.Name));
```

In Linq to entities calling functions like **AsEnumerable()**, **FirstOrDefault()**, **ToList()** will execute the query. So what we do after that functions means that we are dealing with objects not with database.